# Who would use this information to develop better support for hybrid graphics?

Tags: linux, drivers, development, hybrid-graphics, support-cycle

I have a laptop with hybrid graphics and I'm so frustrated that linux doesn't fully support it without any intervention from my side, just like any other Windows machine would normally do.

So I landed on [this page](https://launchpad.net/~hybrid-graphics-linux) which instructed me to run some scripts to gather information about my system and then led to [this page](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lpbugreporter/+bug/752542) which held basically the same information and then led me to [this page](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lpbugreporter/+bug/752542/comments/0) which instructed me to gather some more information.

I package these information in an archive. But sadly, after a discussion with one of the admins of the original page, he clearly stated that there was no much recent effort done to support my brand of graphics card (i.e. Radeon)

So I'm not sure who in the Linux world could make use of the information I gathered to provide better support for HybridGraphics on Linux. I doubt it would be the Linux kernel mailing list. So who would it be if any ?